# Progressbarstyle not working in android

Tags: android, customization, android-progressbar

I'm trying my own theme for my app and I changed some of the widgets using default style. I need the progress bar style as default.

when I used this code for spinner and button its working

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner</item>
</style>
```

But when I try for progressbar its not working

```
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar</item>
```

My progress bar code code in asynctask created dynamically

```
class play extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PropertyTaxpay.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading data");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    //my code

 }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
}
```

What I get:

[image]

But I need with black background. Like the one in holo theme.

like this:

[image]

Comment: How to set Progress bar style? let me see

Comment: or create custom theme and set to your progress bar

Comment: I'm looking for the default theme

Comment: What is your minsdkversion? becoz i have better idea for this

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="11" 
android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Answer (score 3):

Using code you can set `@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar` style for ProgressDialog as:

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new 
    ProgressDialog(PropertyTaxpay.this,android.R.style.Widget_Holo_ProgressBar);
```

or Using xml do it as:

In styles.xml add:

```
<style name="ProgressBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

and in Code pass your own style as second parameter of ProgressDialog constructor :

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new 
    ProgressDialog(PropertyTaxpay.this,R.style.ProgressBar);
```

Comment: If I use this way I get the progress bar on top and its not in the current layout.

Comment: @Yashwanth : you can set position and layout for progressbar accoding to your need

Comment: Pls check the updated question I've done what u said. and if i use styles.xml its black but on top and no transparent layout.